# Iterate over two Feature Classes Inputs in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class, iterator

I use a tool *(Centrality of Urban Network Analysis)* that requires two input files: a polygon layer made of buildings and a Network Dataset. Since my area of analysis is quite huge I divided it into 40 parts. I put all the polygon layers in a folder and all the ND into another.

I want to iterate the process with this tool but problem is, in ModelBuilder, we can only use one iterator, **Iterate Features Classes** in my case. Since we cannot use two iterators in ModelBuilder, I wonder how it is possible to iterate a process when someone is using a tool that requires two different inputs.

Comment: Look at the help file about embedding models, this is how you can loop within a loop.

Comment: Can you give an example of polygon dataset name and the corresponding ND name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a some options here.

**Option 1**: Put a submodel in your main model.  Within that submodel, place another iterator.  That's how you can get around the "One Iterator per model" rule.

**Option 2**: make sure the ND files are named the same way as the polygons, then use [Calculate Value](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) with a script in it that'll change the file extension appropriately, thus giving you the name of the ND file you need.  Then use that as normal.

**Option 3**: Include a border lines layer in the inputs.  Then, inside the iterator create a layer selection (intersects with the current polygon layer).  Then clip your original ND so that you're only using the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can just export your model into a `Python` script and then do all the *powerful* magic with `Python`! Model Builder is too limited, even not able to do if-else flow control. But MB can help you quickly get the stub of an equivalent `Python` script that you can modify to suit your needs.